# Why am I unable to use my paintComponent?

Tags: java, actionlistener, paint, keyevent, actionevent

```
public class Movement implements ActionListener {
    MazeModel model = new MazeModel();
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ //all of the different movement keys
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            model.moveUP(model.getUserY());
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            model.moveLEFT(model.getUserX());
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            model.moveDOWN(model.getUserY());
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            model.moveRIGHT(model.getUserX());
        }
    }
    //no need for either of these at the moment
    public void keyRealeased(KeyEvent e){}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    //painting the image
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage("player.png", model.getUserX(), model.getUserY(), this);
    }
    //every time a key is pressed the screen will repaint the image
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Why am I unable to use `super.paintComponent(g);`?
It says that it is undefined for type Object.

Also it says that drawImage is not applicable to my image. In addition I am unable to `repaint();` when an action is performed in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)`.

Comment: `public class Movement implements ActionListener {` is not a `JFrame` nor a `JPanel`.

Comment: Always precede a method with `@Override` were one overrides: `keyTyped` but especially `paintComponent`. If it would not be overriden. noone calls it.

Answer (score 0):

`public class Movement implements ActionListener {`

your class is not a JFrame nor a JPanel.

Comment: (c/w - will remove if EPF wants to post the same as an answer)

Comment: Nothing will call methods in the action listener which are not overloads. You need to implement the drawing in the component, not the listener

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to extend `JPanel`